# Creating List Parallels

Tags: c#, list

Ive been tasked to create a Form with 2 listboxes and 3 labels.

One listbox is filled with a collection of camping gear. When an item in this listbox is selected by double clicking the item it copies it to the second listbox.  One here then another list with prices will populate the Subtotal for each item that is placed in the second listbox.

I have been told that I should use parallel array so that in the end if items needs to be removed from the second listbox then it would also subtract that from the subtotal in the end.  The key to this application is having a list object in memory parallel to your list box.

For example, you need a list of prices to match the list of names of products available.  You will need the same for the list of items purchased and the list of purchased prices for items selected.  By doing this, you can easily remove an item from an order based on location.

If the user wants to remove item 3 in the items purchased list box, you also remove item 3 from the items purchase list object in memory.  THEN you can call a method that loops through the purchased prices list object to get the total.

Here is my code so far I know that I am close but I cannot seem to figure out the missing piece:

```
private void lstItems_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ////lstItems.DataSource = lstprices;
    // validate item is selected

    // get price of selected item and add to order list
    decimal SubTotalValue = 0;
    int itemIndex = 0;
    decimal ThisPrice = 0;
    {

        try
        {
            if (lstItems.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                lstOrder.Items.Add(lstItems.SelectedItem.ToString());
                itemIndex = int.Parse(lstItems.GetItemText(lstItem.ToString()));
                ThisPrice = lstprices.IndexOf(itemIndex);
                SubTotalValue += ThisPrice;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


        ////lstItems.SelectedIndex = lstprices.SelectedIndex;

        // get string value of selected item and add to order listbox
        lblSubtotal.Text = lstprices.ToString();
        decimal STotal = decimal.Parse(lblSubtotal.Text.ToString());
        decimal SubTotals = STotal * (tax / 100);
        decimal GTotal = calcGrandTotal(STotal, SubTotals);

        //display totals from calculation performing functions
        lblTax.Text = SubTotals.ToString();
        lblTotal.Text = GTotal.ToString();
    }
}
```

I would assume that I would do something similar to this for removing items . Any help would greatly be appreciated.  This code does error at these lines:

```
lstOrder.Items.Add(lstItems.SelectedItem.ToString());
itemIndex = int.Parse(lstItems.GetItemText(lstItem.ToString()));
```

and I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I think if users can select more than one item in 'lstItems' This code has to change as below

```
        for(int i = 0 ; i < lstItems.SelectedItems.Count ; i++)
        {
            lstOrder.Items.Add(lstItems.SelectedItems[i].ToString());
            int itemIndex = int.Parse(lstItems.GetItemText(lstItems.SelectedItems[i]);
        }
```